# How to calculate AUC in coverage graph

Tags: rna-seq, coverage

Is there a way to calculate the area under a curve in a coverage graph?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

I'd like to calculate the AUC per strand per gene in a coverage graph. I have two wig files (sense and antisense) generated from a single bam (RNA-seq) file (using the [strand-coverage](https://github.com/pmenzel/stranded-coverage) software).

Comment: Welcome to the group.  Can you expand on your question to include what tools you are using, what you have tried.  How did you generate the curve and do you have any sample data to help answer your question?

Comment: Hi Bioathlete. I'm totally new in Bioinformatics field. I have not tried much yet due to lack of knowledge, but I edited my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just add up the coverage at each location; that's integration in a nutshell.

Or, alternatively / equivalently, count the total number of reads within the region.